# idea.properties file - InvalidPathException

Tags: pycharm

I configured PyCharm and accidentally entered wrong paths for the following values:

- `idea.config.path`
- `idea.system.path`
- `idea.plugins.path`
- `idea.log.path`

I did this in PyCharm by opening the settings, clicking "Edit custom properties" and then pasting this wrong values for the `idea.properties` file.

This now leads to a startup error of PyCharm and raises `InvalidPathException`.
I found `idea.properties` file, but the mentioned values are not visible there, and I am now wondering how I can change these values?

In PyCharm opened this menu to amend the paths (but I cannot open PyCharm anymore):
Step 1
[image: Step 1]

Step 2
[image: Step 2]

Step 3
[image: Step 3]

Comment: Where's the dialogue in the settings where you changed those values?

Comment: The dialogue appears when you click on the settings in PyCharm and after this "Edit Custom Properties".

Comment: What's the exact breadcrumb? There's no "edit custom properties" in the main settings dialogue.

Comment: I edited my question but I am not hundred percent sure if I understand you correctly? Note, I was not able to change the values in the idea.properties file which is located in the bin folder of the PyCharm installation directory.

Comment: On Windows go to `C:\Users\**your_username_here**\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm**your_version number here**` **you have to change the username and PyCharm version to your specific instalation**. If you empty the file it should work.

Comment: See [the 3rd bullet point](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-platform-properties) where it reads: *"If you cannot start PyCharm, manually create an empty `idea.properties` file in the PyCharm configuration directory."* Follow the link to [config directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory) that explains exactly where the config file is located. But basically, after removing the options you added to that file the IDE will restart. Let us know if it worked!